# Volume mixer stops responding after wake-up of Windows7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, audio

I have windows7 64 over Dell studio XPS, I had few problems with drivers failing to start properly after wake up from hibernation or sleep, but nothing on web is particular about it, so Im going to state my problem and findings here, maybe to grab enough attention of this problem.

**Shockwave plugin one time failed on all three browsers,** IE9, chrome and firefox, couldn't watch YouTube, I had to restart... searched on Adobe site they suggested few things, uninstalling older versions, and making sure the most recent plugin is activated... but that didnt solve it... then I finally noticed that it was the audio driver that fails when I play a YouTube video, and with it, shockwave stops responding...

What I mean by fail is not straight forward, the service is there, and it says it is running (Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoints Builder), and the task is there too (audiodg.exe), and computer manager doesnt say it failed or deactivated, and uninstalling and upgrading or  reinstalling doesnt present any change... it just when **I click on the volume icon to open the volume mixer, it opens, then it stops responding!**

This happens only after wake up, never after restart

it also appeared after I had my MS headset which I use mainly for skype
(a hotfix was described here in 2010 to solve, windows updates since then did not fix the problem) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2122063

The audio wud be fine, when I get a message on **skype** it fails, and it takes Skype with it, nothing on skype tells me that its not working, it just refuses to send the messages i type, and I dont receive any messages... then it hits me again, the volume mixer hanged!

The Wacom driver does that sometimes, after wake up it acts weird... wouldnt respond to pen gestures properly, sometimes responds then stops, responds to a touch as a click... etc.

Anyway the solution to all these problems to me is going through the list of tasks, and services, ending them, and restarting tasks, and everything goes back to normal...

windows updates and hotfixes did not fix it

**EDIT: PS, maybe the fact that my windows is 64 and i keep seeing duplicate tasks one regular and one with "32" appended to some services (like wacom pen)**

Comment: Solution: Do not sleep or hibernate this machine. It is not worth your time or effort to save money on energy.

Comment: no, its not solution im afraid

Comment: I'm curious, why?

Comment: thats more like running away from a problem, i always need to hibernate, i never shut down my laptop, not for energy saving but because i do want to leave everything as is, and go to sleep, and wake up the next day to resume where i stopped

Comment: Im just pointing out that if you take a step back, that does not really accomplish all that much, and trying to figure it out may not be worth your time. I

Comment: yeah ur probably right, i think im the only one in the universe who has this problem! im throwing away my dell, bad choice :(

Comment: Have you updated the BIOS and all the drivers? If so, perhaps try downgrading to previous versions? Just throwing ideas out for you.